# Why do I get different result when I apply StandardScaler function?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, scaling

I created a function for StandardScaler, here it is:

```
def ss_func(dff):
  df_mean = dff.mean()
  df_std = dff.std()
  dff_scaled = (dff - df_mean) / df_std
  return print(dff_scaled)
```

and I used it in the data, and get this result:

```
     first    second     third
0 -0.767772 -0.518494 -1.704506
1  0.383886  1.774325  0.046770
2 -0.658090 -0.612765  0.239047
3  1.590385 -0.340051  0.829734
4 -0.548408 -0.303016  0.588955
```

But when I used StandardScaler from *sklearn.preprocessing*, I see a different result like that:

```
[[-0.85839508 -0.5796934  -1.905696  ]
 [ 0.42919754  1.98375598  0.05229044]
 [-0.73576721 -0.6850922   0.26726224]
 [ 1.77810408 -0.38018853  0.92767112]
 [-0.61313934 -0.33878186  0.6584722 ]]
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in different .std default parameters. Pandas uses `ddof=1` which creates an unbiased estimator, rather than an empirical one (`ddof=0` which numpy would use).

```
def ss_func(dff):
  df_mean = dff.mean()
  df_std = dff.std(ddof=0)
  dff_scaled = (dff - df_mean) / df_std
  return dff_scaled
```

should fix it